# Understanding "attribute_will_change!" method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, activerecord, hstore

I want to overwrite the `store_accessor`'s getter. Which can be found [here](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Store/ClassMethods/store_accessor). Code here:

```rb
# File activerecord/lib/active_record/store.rb, line 74
      def store_accessor(store_attribute, *keys)
        keys = keys.flatten

        _store_accessors_module.module_eval do
          keys.each do |key|
            define_method("#{key}=") do |value|
              write_store_attribute(store_attribute, key, value)
            end

            define_method(key) do
              read_store_attribute(store_attribute, key)
            end
          end
        end

        self.stored_attributes[store_attribute] ||= []
        self.stored_attributes[store_attribute] |= keys
      end
```

I achieved the functionality I was after, however if I were to also overwrite the setter, there is a method that is not clear to me, which is within the `write_store_attribute(...)` method (found [here](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Store/write_store_attribute)).

The code is here:

```rb
# File activerecord/lib/active_record/store.rb, line 108
      def write_store_attribute(store_attribute, key, value)
        attribute = initialize_store_attribute(store_attribute)
        if value != attribute[key]
          send :"#{store_attribute}_will_change!"
          attribute[key] = value
        end
      end
```

The method I don't understand is `"#{whatever_store_att}_will_change!"`.

If I were to overwrite the setter I would use `update_attributes` or `update_column`. Is this method making the assignment `attribute[key]=value` actually modify the field in the DB, making it equivalent to a `update_attributes`?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is part of activemodel's change tracking system, which active record uses to know what it needs to write to the db (if anything).

When you call save on a record, then activerecord creates an update query for all the attributes that it considers changed (and if there are no changed attributes then it does nothing at all).

The accessors that activerecord generates for you handle this for you automatically, but in some cases its useful to tell activerecord that an attribute is dirty and needs changing (for example if you update something in place, circumventing the usual change tracking mechanism).

This is exactly what happens here: when you set a key for the stored attribute - rails modifies the hash (as opposed to assigning a new hash), and so a call to `_will_change!` is needed to keep the change tracking informed that the underlying attribute will need writing to the db the next time save is called.

Comment: thanks! great explanation. A couple of questions: 1) Looking at the same file for *Rails 3.2.13* instead of *Rails 4.x*, I can see that the call to `_will_change!` is done *after* the assignment `attribute[key]=value`, unlike *Rails 4*. I presume this does not matter?. 2) I guess the fact that this is an `Hstore` column is not relevant, right? Since in earlier versions of Rails, there was no possibility to create accessors for `hstore` columns. Or maybe I've got it wrong?

Comment: It shouldn't make any difference. I don't think the hstore stuff matters massively - it's not so different than the serialized columns rails had always has, other than (crucially) the database understanding the serialization